# How to turn an single unification variable into a goal, during proof

Tags: coq

I want to construct an existential variable interactively. I can't use [Grab Existential Variables](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/proof-engine/proof-handling.html#coq:cmd.grab-existential-variables) because I need to fill the existential before I complete the goal.

**Minimal exmaple**
Here is a minimal example (since it's simple, it has other solutions, but it illustrates my question)

```
Context (A:Type).
Parameter P Q: A -> Prop.
Definition filter: forall {a}, P a -> A:= fun a Pa=> a.
Lemma my_lemma:
  forall a b, Q b -> (Q b -> P a) ->
         exists a (H: P a), P (filter H).
  Proof.
  intros ?? H H0.
  do 2 eexists.
```

At this point, there are two solutions that don't answer my questions: (1) I could run (`eauto`) and then do `Grab Existential Variables`, but suppose that eauto doesn't succeed until I instantiate the unification variable; (2) I could just pass the proof term explicitly with `instantiate(1:= H0 H)` (or even `instantiate(1:= ltac:(eauto))`), but assume that the proof of the xistential was tedious and we wished to do it interactively.

What else can we do? We can try to use `cut` or `assert`, like so:

```
match goal with
      |[|- P (filter ?x)] =>
       match type of x with
       | ?T => assert (HH:T) by eauto
       end
      end.
```

But HH is not in the context of the unification variable, so it can't be instantiated.

```
  instantiate(1:=HH). (* Instance is not well-typed in the environment of ?H. *)
```

As far as I can tell, the only way to solve this is to use `Show Existentials`, see the type of the variable copy it by hand, roll back the proof to before the unification was introduced and construct the variable there. In the example it looks like this:

```
Lemma my_lemma:
  forall a b, Q b -> (Q b -> P a) ->
         exists a (H: P a), P (filter H).
Proof.
  intros ?? H H0.
  do 2 eexists.
  Show Existentials.  
  Restart. (* This command restores the proof editing process to the original goal. *)
  intros ?? H H0.
  assert (HH:P a) by eauto.
  eexists; exists HH.
  auto.
Qed.
```

Obviously, I would like to avoid this workflow. So, anyway to turn the existential variables into subgoals?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best bet is probably to avoid creating the existential variable as an evar in the first place. You don't have to construct the variable by hand to do this; if you can identify where it's created, you can wrap the offending tactic with `unshelve t`, which turns all evars created by `t` into goals. Where this might be difficult is if the relevant tactic is deep inside some automation and difficult to identify or change.

Comment: Thank you! It is not what I have in mind but it's better than other options. Unfortunately, I'm in the middle of a large development with long automation, which I can't wrap with `unshelve`. I was hoping for more fine grain control of shelving/unshelving. Maybe one day we will get `unshelve num`, which will unshelve a single goal.

Comment: Just tested this in my development and unshelve created ~50 more goals that can't be discharged automatically. I just want to unshelve one of those!

Comment: Yeah, it's a pretty coarse-grained tool and I'm not that surprised it unshelves too many things.